# tokenizer does not work

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[trim]{tokenizer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xfor}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter


\def\bb{\compilation} % \combilation has {one,two,three}

\newcommand{\chapterInputa}[4][all

]{%

% It does not work 

  \def\SourceA{\bb}
    \whiledo{\not\equal{\SourceA}{}}
    {
        \GetTokens{TokenOneA}{TokenTwoB}{\SourceA}
            BB TOken- \TokenOneA \\
        \let\SourceA\TokenTwoB
    }

% its work fine

  \def\Source{#1}
    \whiledo{\not\equal{\Source}{}}
    {
        \GetTokens{TokenOne}{TokenTwo}{\Source}
            ELE- \TokenOne \\
        \let\Source\TokenTwo
    }


\chapter{#3\label{#4}}
    \input{#2}
}

}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The change in two code is passing parameter as `#1` and variable name.
What's wrong with the code.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please edit your code so that it starts with `\documentclass` and shows all packages used. As posted it uses several non standard commands with no indication of where or how they are defined, so there is not much help we can offer.

Comment: In the first `\whiledo` `\SourceA` is expanded to `\bb` first. Then `\bb` is expanded to `\compilation`, but the latter is undefined.

Comment: As posted your code produces `! Too many }'s. l.45 }` If the spurious `}` is deleted then the example runs without error. However it doesn't use any of the macros it defines and you haven't said what you intend those macros to do so it is still impossible to guess what help you are looking for.

Comment: I wanted to compare two comma separated list. If the two list has at least one same element then it should load the chapter "    
\chapter{#3\label{#4}}
    \input{#2}"